# Full screen figure with caption

Tags: graphics

I am trying to get an image to fill/cover whole page. However, still I want a caption with the standard figure number for reference. Where the caption appear is not that important.. Just somewhere on the image.

Normally I insert images like below. How can I get the image to cover the header og footer? And 100% of the width.

(I know a printer will not be able to print to the edges, that's OK)

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.00\textwidth]{billeder/Skitseprojektering/Bindinger/kort/Jordartskort.png}
    \caption{Jordarter i projektområdet \parencite{skaermkort_graa,vejmidte_vejnavne,jordart_GEUS_GIS}.}
    \label{fig:jordbundsanalyse}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Normal image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An [`incgraph`](https://ctan.org/pkg/incgraph) solution:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{incgraph}

\begin{document}
\Huge
Normal page before the image page. Ref to Figure~\ref{img:image page} on page~\pageref{img:image page}

% `inctext` environment will typeset its contents in a separate page
\begin{inctext}[paper=current,label={img:image page},bookmark={A huge ABC}]
  \begin{minipage}{\paperwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{Title}
  \end{minipage}
\end{inctext}

Another normal page after the image page
\end{document}
```

[image]

[`adjustbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) has more advanced scaling options in case you want to set the scaling more automatic.

**Update:**

To push the image to top, use

```tex
  \begin{minipage}[t][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}
    [...]
    \vfill
  \end{minipage}
```

Full example

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{incgraph}

\begin{document}
\Huge
Normal page before the image page. Ref to Figure~\ref{img:image page} on page~\pageref{img:image page}

% `inctext` environment will typeset its contents in a separate page
\begin{inctext}[paper=current,label={img:image page},bookmark={A huge ABC}]
  \begin{minipage}[t][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{Title}
    \vfill
  \end{minipage}
\end{inctext}

Another normal page after the image page
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Is the ref working correctly? It points to page 1.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Yes the ref works well. Here 1 stands for Figure 1. And `\refpage{...}` will typeset 2, as expected.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks! Seems like a good package. Will look into it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It fit my needs apart from one thing: How can you place the image in the top of the page?

Comment: @pstidsen Answer updated.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the caption on the facing page for twoside documents. In the example it is on the lower left page:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
Normal page before the image page \ref{img:image page}

\Blindtext

\hvFloat[FULLPAGE,capPos=left]{figure}%
  {\includegraphics[FULLPAGE]{example-image}}
  {\blindtext}% the caption
  {img:image page}

\Blindtext

Another normal page after the image page
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using `\makebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=1.75\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{fig:key}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please what is your documentclass? Can you provide to put a label of the figure with a caption? +1

Comment: The document class I've used is article.

Answer (score 1):

This overlaps the caption and the image.  The image takes up no space, although the baseline is located at the top of the text area.  The minipage takes up the entire text area, with the caption at the bottom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
\rlap{\raisebox{\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep-\height}[0pt][0pt]%
  {\hspace*{\dimexpr -1in-\oddsidemargin}\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}}}%
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][b]{\textwidth}% fill entire text area
\caption{Test}% will be even with bottom of text area
\end{minipage}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```