# How to reset document geometry on floating full page image

Tags: graphics, floats, geometry

For my thesis I want some images to use a full-page without creating a page break at the insert AND changing the page document geometry of only the image page.

I have found that `\begin{figure}[p]` forces a full page dedicated to the figure and this works for me.

I have found that `\usepackage[<variable>]{geometry}` has a `\newgeometry{}` and a `\restoregeometry` but this does not work for me (following the manual for the The geometry package)

My preamble runs `\usepackage[left=8cm,right=1cm,top=2cm,bottom=4cm,marginparwidth=7cm,marginparsep=0.5cm]{geometry}`

My main also runs

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove line in header
\setlength\headsep{3cm}
\setlength\textheight{20cm}
\setlength\footskip{4,3cm}
```

for the record.

I'm currently running this figure code without any luck

```
\begin{figure}[p]
\newgeometry{}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Fig/Co_Creation/DivCon.pdf}
 \caption{Planned divergence and convergence in the co-creation process}
 \label{fig:diagramDC}
\clearpage
\restoregeometry
\end{figure}
```

Ideally, I'd like to remove any content in the header and footer on these pages as well.

Kind regards

Leo

Comment: It is easier to overlap the margins than change them.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623907/full-screen-figure-with-caption/623998?r=SearchResults&s=1|29.7082#623998

Comment: If the answer meets your original request please accept it by checking the green tickmark on left side of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define what new geometry want. Also both `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` should go outside of the figure environment.

With `\pagestyle{empty}` you cancel all headers and footers. You can then restore the fancy style or invoke another.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % only dummy tet <<<
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[left=8cm,right=1cm,top=2cm,bottom=4cm,marginparwidth=7cm,marginparsep=0.5cm,showframe]{geometry} % added showframe <<<

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove line in header


\begin{document}
1.  \kant[1-3]

    \newgeometry{left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm,marginparwidth=0cm,marginparsep=0cm}
    \pagestyle{empty} % no headers nor footers
    \begin{figure}[p]       
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Planned divergence and convergence in the co-creation process}
        \label{fig:diagramDC}               
    \end{figure}

    \restoregeometry        
    \pagestyle{fancy} % restore headers and footers <<<

2.  \kant[2]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is close, but I lack the float effect, i.e. the text breaks at the location of the image and  creates half full pages of text. Is there a way to have the text continue?

Comment: @Leo Heinzl  `\newgeometry` will start a new page. LaTeX is doing its best.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answers. I will continue with your solution and manually rearrange in the end.